# Tab underline returning to the first tab on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I haven't used tabs in my project because of some UI constraint, instead I have used three buttons with viewpager which work as a tab. Below the three buttons I have used three views which are working as tabs underline.

The problem is, when the screen is rotated, correct viewpager is showing up, but underline is coming below the first button, however, it should be below the currently selected button.

Comment: plz post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

you must store the view position number  (for example tab number 2 or tab number 3) in a bundle using  [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and reading back it from [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).